# Hive - compare data between tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to compare data between 2 external tables (A and A') with the same columns and i actually make some sql scripts to do this but is not enough efficient and robust. there are a way to  do this with UDAF or external tools?

**Here one sample:**

**Table A**

```
+----+----+----+
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
+----+----+----+
| 01 | A  | 02 |
| 02 | B  | 03 |
| 03 | C  | 04 |
+----+----+----+
```

**Table A'**

```
+----+----+----+
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
+----+----+----+
| 01 | B  | 02 |
| 02 | B  | 03 |
| 04 | D  | 04 |
+----+----+----+
```

**Output**

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  C1  |  C2  |  C3  | C1'  | C2'  | C3'  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 01   | A    | 02   | 01   | B    | 02   |
| 03   | C    | 04   | null | null | null |
| null | null | null | 04   | D    | 04   |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the custom MR  Program for this. We have already had these kind of problems. You have to write a custom MR Program are custom UDF. There is no in build method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new tool to compare data. 
DiffTool ([https://dataq.io/](https://dataq.io)) is a UI based data comparison tool that can be used across data sources like RDBMS, Hadoop(Hive) or text files (CSV & JSON). DiffTool Compares datasets based on key(s), and some of the features include:

controlling data volume using custom filters, 
Transforming columns using SQL expressions, 
The ability to scale using distributed architecture, 
And analyzing results intuitively with rich visualization

Comment: The tool is dataq.io

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a UDF if the comparison id b/w rows from table A and table A' based on a join condition which in this case i believe is the first column C1.

Approach:

```
select UDF_FUNCTION(a.c1,a.c2.a.c3, A'.c2,a'.c3) from A JOIN A' ON (A.c1=a'.c1)
```

In the UDF you can compare the values as per your requirement and return an array or delimited text.

Also what do you mean by

> some sql scripts to do this but is not enough efficient and robust